# How to use Regular Expression to return the string of an array element that contains the specific word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

How to use Regular Expression to return the string of an array element that contains the word "Netflix"

Here is what I tried:

```
const arr = [
    'Sweet TV - some description',
    'MEGOGO - some description.',
    'Netflix - some description.',
];

let newArr = []

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    newArr = arr.regExp(/Netflix/gm)[i]
}


console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Why not simply `arr.find((elem) => elem.includes("Netflix"))`?

Comment: Also, consider the case where the original array has the keyword in more than one element.  When you assign the value to the new array, you probably want to assign the value at an index in the array....

Comment: Thanks so much @SebastianSimon. Yep, this way is much more easier.